# Rails 4 renaming column with index

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, jruby, database-migration, ruby-on-rails-4.2

According to [this](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/upgrading_ruby_on_rails.html#active-record), in rails 4, renaming a column will rename the index also.

```
class TestMigration < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    binding.pry
    rename_column :feature_roles, :feature_id, :test_id
    binding.pry
  end
end
```

When I've listed the indices of this table before migration, the name of the particular index is `index_feature_roles_on_feature_id` and even after migration also, it remains the same. Why is it not updating to `index_feature_roles_on_test_id`?

I'm using Jruby 9.1.12.0 (ruby 2.3.3)

Comment: Check out the actual `structure.sql` diff.

Comment: I'm using schema.rb and the corresponding entry after migration looks like:
```
add_index "feature_roles", ["test_id"], name: "index_feature_roles_on_feature_id", using: :btree
```

Comment: So the index changes, it's just that the name remains the same.

Comment: yes. but later on, if I write a migration to remove the index by its name, it will fail

Comment: It will work if you use the old name.

Comment: the problem is I'm upgrading JRuby. It was working as expected with older version. I don't want to change existing db migrations

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/165635/discussion-between-vijith-mv-and-ndn).

Answer (score 0):

Probably the name of the index is not database generated, its what we give while creation of index in this case the name of the index wont get any update but definitely the reference will be updated and this will work the same way.

Still you want to update the index name you could drop index and recreate it.

```
DROP INDEX index_feature_roles_on_feature_id;
```

post that recreate index on the updated column as

```
CREATE INDEX index_feature_roles_on_test_id ON feature_roles;
```

This could be helpful if in long run can be a case where several other developers might be working on the same thing which will remove the confusion.

Comment: Thanks for the response. First thing, the index names are not explicitly specified while adding them. Second, this is not a good practice to update existing migrations.
This was working with my old dev env. I'm now trying to upgrade my jruby version from 9.1.6 to 9.1.12

Comment: I too appreciate of not updating the existing migrations. I am just focusing on adding new migration for delete & creation of index with updated name. :)

Comment: Rails 4 ensures the rename column migration will change the index name also (which is not happening now, particularly after the jruby upgrade)

Answer (score 0):

There is a potential bug in [activerecord-jdbc-adapter](https://github.com/jruby/activerecord-jdbc-adapter) gem. Check out the GitHub [issue](https://github.com/jruby/activerecord-jdbc-adapter/issues/985) for details.